# How to solve system of two equation with two unknown and using substitution?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$\begin{align}
a^2 - b^2 = 3\\
a \cdot b = 2
\end{align}$$

In aforementioned equations, we can mentally find out the value of $a = 2, b = 1$. But what is the general way to solve this system algebraically?

I tried to use substitution but I got stuck. Rearranging two equations to $a^2=b^2+3$ and $a^2 \cdot b^2 = 2^2$ we will get:

$$ (b^2 + 3) \cdot b^2 = 4\\
\rightarrow b^4 + 3b^2 = 4\\
\rightarrow b^2(b^2 + 3) = 4\\
$$

Then what?

Alternatively can we solve by elimination?

Comment: What you wrote is **not** a linear system.

Comment: @heropup you are right. I fixed it.

Comment: Note that a=-2 and b=-1 is also a solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HINT:

$$\implies b^4+3b^2-4=0\iff (b^2+4)(b^2-1)=0$$

Then from the second equation, find corresponding value of $a$ for each value of $b$

Then, check whether each pair of $(a,b)$ satisfy the first

---

Alternatively, $$(a^2+b^2)^2=(a^2-b^2)^2+(2ab)^2$$

Comment: Thank for thorough explanation. I just did not understand the alternative solution. Is it alternative way to solve the HINT section or it is totally another way for finding the solution?

Comment: @Baqer, The second one is an independent method.

Comment: @Baqer, We have $$(a^2+b^2)^2=3^2+4^2=25\implies a^2+b^2=\pm5,$$ and we already have $$a^2-b^2$$ So, find $a^2,b^2$ and check for each pair of (a,b) if they satisfy the second equation

Answer (score 3):

Your last equation, $b^2+3b^2-4=0$ is a quadratic in $b^2$.  You can define $c=b^2$ and find $c^2+3c-4=0$.  Maybe you can factor this, if not you can use the quadratic formula.  Solve for $c$, then take the square root to get $b$.  This works for quartics that only have the even power terms.